# codeigniter 2.1.3 multilanguage website how to?

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

codeigniter 2.1.3 multilanguage website how to ?

i have on /language/english and /language/french

this french
$lang['user_login']           = 'Connecté';

this english
$lang['user_login']           = 'Login';

the language file its called user_lang.php

on the controller contructor i have this :

```
$this->load->helper('url');         
    $this->load->helper('language');
```

on the function index i have this :

```
public function index()
{

           $this->lang->load('user', 'french');
```

....

on the view i have the following :

```
<div class="pageTitle"><?php echo $this->lang->line('user_login');?></div>

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Language files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['language'] = array('lang1', 'lang2');
|
| NOTE: Do not include the "_lang" part of your file.  For example
| "codeigniter_lang.php" would be referenced as array('codeigniter');
|
*/

$autoload['language'] = array('user');
```

the question is that the website is working its going to the user_lang.php
to get the word login

but only goes to the english file

```
 $this->lang->load('user', 'french');
```

iam doing this above , and its not working never reads the french file

i have another question , how can i get this working so i can switch languages with a anchor or href

thanks
Pedro

Comment: <div class="pageTitle"><?php echo $this->lang->line('user_login');?></div>

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function like:

```
function language($language){

        $language = urldecode($language);

        switch($language){

            case "French":
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_id', 2);
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_name', 'french');
                redirect('/', 'refresh');

            break;

            case "Russian":
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_id', 3);
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_name', 'russian');
                redirect('/', 'refresh');

            break;

            default: //default is English
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_id', 1);
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_name', 'english');
                redirect('/', 'refresh');

            break;  

        }

    }
```

And I would change languages navigating to: http://www.domain.com/controller/language/French

Then in every controller or in constructor of each controller class I would check for the lang_id and lang_name session. If sessions are set, I would use them. Else the default language from the config will automatically load. For example:

```
$lang = $this->session->userdata('lang_name');
if(!isset($lang)){ //load default language 
                $this->lang->load('home');
                $data = array(
                    'title' => lang('page_title')
                );
//etc etc

            }else{ //load language from session
                $this->lang->load('home', $this->session->userdata('lang_name'));

                $data = array(
                    'title' => lang('page_title')
                );      
//etc etc       
            }
```

Comment: where should i create this class

function language($language){

Comment: Create it as a function inside a model. Or whatever way suits you

Answer (score 0):

in my welcome controller

```
public function french()
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('lang_id', 2);
        $this->session->set_userdata('lang_name', 'french');
         $DContent['page_details'] = array('page_title' => 'Index of onplans');
         $Dheader = array();
         $Dsidebar = array();
         $Dfooter = array();
         $Dmeta = array('meta_title'=>'Welcome to onplans','meta_descricao'=>'onplans');



         $this->template->write_view('meta', 'html/meta',  $Dmeta, true);
         $this->template->write_view('header', 'html/header', $Dheader, true);
         $this->template->write_view('content', 'onplans/frenchset', $DContent,true);
         $this->template->write_view('sidebar', 'html/sidebar');
         $this->template->write_view('footer', 'html/footer');
         $this->template->render();

    }

    public function english()
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('lang_id', 3);
        $this->session->set_userdata('lang_name', 'english');
         $DContent['page_details'] = array('page_title' => 'Index of onplans');
         $Dheader = array();
         $Dsidebar = array();
         $Dfooter = array();
         $Dmeta = array('meta_title'=>'Welcome to onplans','meta_descricao'=>'onplans');



         $this->template->write_view('meta', 'html/meta',  $Dmeta, true);
         $this->template->write_view('header', 'html/header', $Dheader, true);
         $this->template->write_view('content', 'onplans/englishset', $DContent,true);
         $this->template->write_view('sidebar', 'html/sidebar');
         $this->template->write_view('footer', 'html/footer');
         $this->template->render();

    }
```

on the destination controller called user

```
$this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->helper('language');


        print_r('lang_session'.$this->session->userdata('lang_name'));


        $lang = $this->session->userdata('lang_name');

        if(!isset($lang)){ //load default language 

                $this->lang->load('user');


            }else{ //load language from session
 print_r('lang :'.$this->session->userdata('lang_name'));
                $this->lang->load('user',$this->session->userdata('lang_name')); //);    
            }
```

now its working